# Как создать ярлык для заданной activity?

Tags: kotlin, activity, android-manifest

Как сделать переход на другую activity с ярлыка на рабочем столе ? Возможно ли такое сделать вообще ?

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RotatingActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="RotatingActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: попробуйте дать второй активити такой же <intent-filter> как и у Main.

Comment: пробовал, создаётся ярлык с заданным названием, но переход происходит на основную Activity(

Comment: Переходит туда куда напишете, приведите свои наброски.